# Unable to find column with logical name in table while deploying with Docker

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, docker

I have a problem which only happen when I'm deploying my application on a remote server (using Docker).
On my environment, and the environments of my coworkers, the following code works, but when we try to deploy on the remote server, we have this hibernate error : **Unable to find column with logical name id_region in table Person**.

Here are the Spring Entities :

```java
/** REGION **/
@Entity
public class Region {
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```java
/** PERSON **/
@Entity
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String surname;
    private Region regionByIdRegion;
    private Collection<House> houses;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_PERSON")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_PERSON", 
        sequenceName = "SEQ_PERSON", 
        allocationSize = 1)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "surname")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_region", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Region getRegionByIdRegion() {
        return regionByIdRegion;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_HOUSE", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOUSE")})
    public Collection<House> getHouses() {
        return houses;
    }
}
```

```java
/** HOUSE **/
@Entity
public class House {
    private Integer id;
    private String personName;
    private Region regionByIdRegion;
    private Person person;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_HOUSE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_HOUSE", sequenceName = "SEQ_HOUSE", 
        allocationSize = 1)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "person_name")
    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_region", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Region getRegionByIdRegion() {
        return regionByIdRegion;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_name", referencedColumnName = "surname", 
        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_region", referencedColumnName = "id_region", 
        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public House getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

The problem is located at the getter *getPerson()* of the House entity. The field **person_name** is not a foreign key but it references Person. The goal is to get the entity Person which have :
house.person_name = person.surname AND house.id_region = person.id_region.

We tried to replace **@JoinColumn(name = "id_region", referencedColumnName = "id_region", insertable = false, updatable = false)** by **@Where(clause = "id_region = id_region")**. There is no more hibernate error, but we don't get the good entity. I think it is because both id_region fields are taken on the House table, so it's always true. I can't find a way to identify each field more precisely to have the where clause like house.id_region = person.id_region.

As I said before, this code works on local environment, but not on the remote one because of the error **Unable to find column with logical name id_region in table Person**. Does anyone have an idea why ?

Comment: Look at your table in db where your app connects on the remote environment, maybe your column is missing.

Comment: @zlaval the column is there. And we use liquibase changelogs to create the databases, so I'm sure the databases are the same on my environment and the remote one.